# Laravel Backpack - Show specific attribute from relationship function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have the registered `Comment` model which has a `User` reference, like this:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

This function returns an instance of a `User`, and that's correct, but I don't know how to register the `User` column the get que `user` property using Backpack. Instead, I'm get a JSON representation of my model:

[image]

So, **how do I get a specific field from my relationship function**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [the select column](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#section-select) is a perfect match for you. Just use it in your EntityCrudController's `setup()` method, like so:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
   // 1-n relationship
   'label' => "User", // Table column heading
   'type' => "select",
   'name' => 'user_id', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
   'entity' => 'user', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
   'attribute' => "user", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
   'model' => "App\Models\User", // foreign key model
]);
```

The "attribute" tells CRUD what to show in the table cell (the name, the id, etc).

Comment: Thanks @tabacitu. Your solution worked. The comments were also really useful. About the 'type' key, what 'select' means in this context?

Comment: When defining a field, “type” tells crud what kind of field you want to show to the user. There are 44+ field types available in Backpack, check them out here - https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields

Comment: Oups you’re talking about columns. Same thing, here are the column types - https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
$user = $comment->user->user;
```

You'll get 'test'; (from your example)

It may seem confusing because your User model has a user attribute. Maybe you can call it 'name' instead of 'user'. That way you'll call it:

```
$username = $comment->user->name;
```

Remember to check if the relationship exists before calling a property on the related model.

```
if(!is_null($comment->user)) {
    $username = $comment->user->user;
}
```

Or:

```
$username = !is_null($comment->user) ? $comment->user->user : 'No user';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get some field from deeper relation, you can use closure column type:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
        'label'    => trans('backend.column_names.agency_linked_service'),
        'name'     => 'agency_service_id',
        'type'     => 'closure',
        'function' => function (AgencyLinkedServices $entry) {
            return $entry->agencyService->agencyCategory->title;
        }
    ]);
```